# Why does the following html+css create a div that is off the bottom of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to create a jsFiddle of this, but it doesn't work to reproduce my problem. The Problem is that when I open the following page in webkit (Chrome on XP, or Safari on iOS), the  3rd (blue) div is off the bottom of the page, when what I want is it to be at the bottom.

I am aware that I have some unecessary style applied; that is because I have simplified it as much as I can from a page where I need those attributes set, and removing stops the problem being reproduced.

Page code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .A {
        background: red;
        float: left;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
      }
      .B {
        background: green;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .C {
        background: blue;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="A">
      1
      <div class="B">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="C">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `height: 100%` from `.B` to `.A`

The problem is that your containing element (div A) has no height defined, so will auto size to fit it's content. div B is nested inside that and has a 100% height defined, so div A will be 100% + div C, causing div C to go off the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Of course! Thanks. Though it does pose another question; How do I get my green div to then fill the area that the top red and bottom blue divs occupy. Oh well, I'll look into that next, in fact I think I may need to construct my page layout in a different way to get that working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A relatively simple restructure could accomplish that:
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
      .A {
        background: green;
        float: left;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .B {
        background: red;
      }
      .C {
        background: blue;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="A">
      <div class="B">
        1
       <div class="C">
          3
       </div>
      </div>
        2
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

> Apply this class on the last div which you want to show at the bottom
>   of page

```
.footer
 {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    float:left; 
    z-index:999;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:30px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
```

}

Comment: only moved it half of the way up, and I'm not exactly sure what all of those were supposed to achieve. Thank you for trying, but Stephen Lloyd explained it.